# Find and remove DOS line endings on Ubuntu

Tags: bash, unix, sed, awk, grep

I have found that many of my files have DOS line endings.   In VI they look like this: "^M".
I don't want to modify files that don't have these DOS line endings.  How do I do this using a bash script?  Thanks!

EV

Answer (score 19, accepted):

```
grep -URl ^M . | xargs fromdos
```

grep gets you a list of all files under the current directory that have DOS line endings.

`-U` makes grep consider line endings instead of stripping them away by default

`-R` makes it recursive

`-l` makes it list only the filenames and not the matching lines

then you're piping that list into the converter command (which is `fromdos` on ubuntu, `dos2unix` where i come from).

**NOTE:** don't actually type `^M`.  instead, you'll need to press `<Ctrl-V>` then `<Ctrl-M>` to insert the `^M` character and make grep understand what you're going for.  or, you could type in `$'\r'` in place of `^M` (but i think that may only work for bash...).

Comment: grep -URl ^M . | xargs fromdos ?

Comment: The Ubuntu package, for installation, is called "tofrodos".

Comment: On tcsh, and probably on csh too, you can get the same effect with `grep -URl "\r" . | xargs fromdos`.

Comment: if you need it to work for files with spaces in their names, try `grep -URl ^M . | xargs -I{} dos2unix "{}"` instead.

Answer (score 5):

One way using `GNU coreutils`:

```
< file.txt tr -d '\r'
```

Answer (score 4):

On ubuntu, you use the `fromdos` utility

```
fromdos test.txt
```

> The above example would take a MS-DOS or Microsoft Windows file or other file with different line separators and format the file with new line separators to be read in Linux and Unix.

Answer (score 1):

Many options are there..you can try with any of these.. http://www.theunixschool.com/2011/03/different-ways-to-delete-m-character-in.html

Answer (score 1):

```
cat origin_file.txt | sed "s/^M//" > dest_file.txt
```

You have to do the same thing mentioned above, ctl-V then ctl-M to get that character. This is preferable for me because it is portable across many platforms and keeps it simple within bash.

on ubuntu I also find this works:

cat origin_file.txt | sed "s/\r//" > dest_file.txt

Answer (score 0):

you can use the command:

```
   dos2ux file.in>file.out or:
```

in perl:

```
perl -pi -e 's/\r//g' your_file
```

alternatively you can do:

- open in vi
- go to command mode
- type `:%s/[ctrl-V][CTRL-M]//g`

Answer (score 0):

Note if you're converting multi-byte files you need to take extra care, and should probably try to use the correct iconv or recode from-encoding specifications.

If it's a plain ASCII file, both of the below methods would work.

The `flip` program, in Debian the package is also called `flip`, can handle line-endings. From the manual:

```
When asked to convert a file to the same format that  it already 
has, flip  causes  no change to the file. Thus to convert all
files to **IX format you can type

flip -u *

and all files will end up right, regardless of whether they were 
in MS-DOS or in **IX format to begin with. This also works in the
opposite direction.
```

Or you could use GNU recode:

```
< /etc/passwd recode ..pc | tee a b > /dev/null
file a b
```

Output:

```
a: ASCII text, with CRLF line terminators
b: ASCII text, with CRLF line terminators
```

Convert to unix line-endings:

```
recode pc.. a b
file a b
```

Output:

```
a: ASCII text
b: ASCII text
```

recode abbreviates dos line-endings as `pc`, so the logic with `pc..` is: convert from pc format to the default, which is latin1 with unix line-endings.

Answer (score 0):

A modification to the Winning answer if you need to filter by file ending

```
grep -URl ^M . | grep .php | xargs dos2unix
```

I used dos2unix instead of fromdos but the effect should be the same.