# Bash script expecting then, when else is needed

Tags: bash, shell, syntax-error, ubuntu-12.04, graphhopper

I am trying to run a shell script called graphhopper.sh in Ubuntu 12.04 which was given by a website. When I run it, terminal produces

```
: not found.sh: 2: graphhopper.sh: 
graphhopper.sh: 39: graphhopper.sh: Syntax error: "else" unexpected (expecting "then")
```

The lines which start from 37 in the shell file are,

```
   if [ ${OSM_FILE: -4} == ".pbf" ]; then
       wget -O $OSM_FILE $LINK
    else    
       # make sure aborting download does not result in loading corrupt osm file
       TMP_OSM=temp.osm
       wget -O - $LINK | bzip2 -d > $TMP_OSM
       mv $TMP_OSM $OSM_FILE
    fi

    if [ ! -f "$OSM_FILE" ]; then
      echo "ERROR couldn't download or extract OSM file $OSM_FILE ... exiting"
      exit
    fi
  else
    echo "## using existing osm file $OSM_FILE"
  fi
```

This is the whole shell script.

```
#!/bin/bash

GH_HOME=$(dirname $0)
JAVA=$JAVA_HOME/bin/java
if [ "x$JAVA_HOME" = "x" ]; then
 JAVA=java
fi

vers=`$JAVA -version 2>&1 | grep "java version" | awk '{print $3}' | tr -d \"`
bit64=`$JAVA -version 2>&1 | grep "64-Bit"`
if [ "x$bit64" != "x" ]; then
  vers="$vers (64bit)"
fi
echo "## using java $vers from $JAVA_HOME"

CONFIG=config.properties
if [ ! -f "config.properties" ]; then
  cp config-example.properties $CONFIG
fi

ACTION=$1
FILE=$2

USAGE="./graphhopper.sh import|ui|test <your-osm-file>"
if [ "x$ACTION" = "x" ]; then
 echo -e "## action $ACTION not found. try \n$USAGE"
fi

function ensureOsmXml { 
  if [ ! -s "$OSM_FILE" ]; then
    echo "File not found '$OSM_FILE'. Press ENTER to get it from: $LINK"
    echo "Press CTRL+C if you do not have enough disc space or you don't want to download several MB."
    read -e

    echo "## now downloading OSM file from $LINK and extracting to $OSM_FILE"

    if [ ${OSM_FILE: -4} == ".pbf" ]; then
       wget -O $OSM_FILE $LINK
    else    
       # make sure aborting download does not result in loading corrupt osm file
       TMP_OSM=temp.osm
       wget -O - $LINK | bzip2 -d > $TMP_OSM
       mv $TMP_OSM $OSM_FILE
    fi

    if [ ! -f "$OSM_FILE" ]; then
      echo "ERROR couldn't download or extract OSM file $OSM_FILE ... exiting"
      exit
#    fi
  else
    echo "## using existing osm file $OSM_FILE"
  fi
}

function ensureMaven {
  # maven home existent?
  if [ "x$MAVEN_HOME" = "x" ]; then
    # not existent but probably is maven in the path?
    MAVEN_HOME=`mvn -v | grep "Maven home" | cut -d' ' -f3`
    if [ "x$MAVEN_HOME" = "x" ]; then
      # try to detect previous downloaded version
      MAVEN_HOME="$GH_HOME/maven"
      if [ ! -f "$MAVEN_HOME/bin/mvn" ]; then
        echo "No Maven found in the PATH. Now downloading+installing it to $MAVEN_HOME"
        cd "$GH_HOME"
        MVN_PACKAGE=apache-maven-3.0.5
        wget -O maven.zip http://www.eu.apache.org/dist/maven/maven-3/3.0.5/binaries/$MVN_PACKAGE-bin.zip
        unzip maven.zip
        mv $MVN_PACKAGE maven
        rm maven.zip
      fi
    fi
  fi
}

function packageCoreJar {
  if [ ! -f "$JAR" ]; then
    echo "## now building graphhopper jar: $JAR"
    echo "## using maven at $MAVEN_HOME"
    #mvn clean
    "$MAVEN_HOME/bin/mvn" -f "$GH_HOME/core/pom.xml" -DskipTests=true install assembly:single > /tmp/graphhopper-compile.log
    returncode=$?
    if [[ $returncode != 0 ]] ; then
        echo "## compilation failed"
        cat /tmp/graphhopper-compile.log
        exit $returncode
    fi      
  else
    echo "## existing jar found $JAR"
  fi
}

function prepareEclipse {
 ensureMaven   
 packageCoreJar
 cp core/target/graphhopper-*-android.jar android/libs/   
}


## now handle actions which do not take an OSM file
if [ "x$ACTION" = "xclean" ]; then
 rm -rf */target
 exit

elif [ "x$ACTION" = "xeclipse" ]; then
 prepareEclipse
 exit

elif [ "x$ACTION" = "xandroid" ]; then
 prepareEclipse
 "$MAVEN_HOME/bin/mvn" -f "$GH_HOME/android/pom.xml" install android:deploy android:run
 exit
fi

if [ "x$FILE" = "x" ]; then
  echo -e "no file specified? try \n$USAGE"
  exit
fi

# NAME = file without extension if any
NAME="${FILE%.*}"

if [ ${FILE: -4} == ".osm" ]; then
   OSM_FILE=$FILE
elif [ ${FILE: -4} == ".pbf" ]; then
   OSM_FILE=$FILE
elif [ ${FILE: -7} == ".osm.gz" ]; then
   OSM_FILE=$FILE
else
   # no end default to osm
   OSM_FILE=$NAME.osm
fi

GRAPH=$NAME-gh
VERSION=`grep  "<name>" -A 1 pom.xml | grep version | cut -d'>' -f2 | cut -d'<' -f1`
JAR=core/target/graphhopper-$VERSION-jar-with-dependencies.jar

# file without path (.osm.gz or osm.bz2 is also possible)
TMP=$(basename "$FILE")
TMP="${TMP%.*}"
TMP="${TMP%.*}"


if [ "x$TMP" = "xunterfranken" ]; then
 LINK="http://download.geofabrik.de/openstreetmap/europe/germany/bayern/unterfranken.osm.bz2"
 JAVA_OPTS="-XX:PermSize=60m -XX:MaxPermSize=60m -Xmx200m -Xms200m" 
elif [ "x$TMP" = "xgermany" ]; then
 LINK=http://download.geofabrik.de/openstreetmap/europe/germany.osm.bz2

 # Info: for import we need a more memory than for just loading it
 JAVA_OPTS="-XX:PermSize=60m -XX:MaxPermSize=60m -Xmx1600m -Xms1600m" 
else 
 LINK=`echo $NAME | tr '_' '/'`
 if [ ${FILE: -4} == ".osm" ]; then 
   LINK="http://download.geofabrik.de/$LINK-latest.osm.bz2"
 else
   LINK="http://download.geofabrik.de/$LINK-latest.osm.pbf"
 fi
 if [ "x$JAVA_OPTS" = "x" ]; then
  JAVA_OPTS="-XX:PermSize=60m -XX:MaxPermSize=60m -Xmx1000m -Xms1000m" 
 fi
fi



ensureOsmXml
ensureMaven
packageCoreJar

echo "## now $ACTION. JAVA_OPTS=$JAVA_OPTS"

if [ "x$ACTION" = "xui" ] || [ "x$ACTION" = "xweb" ]; then
 export MAVEN_OPTS="$MAVEN_OPTS $JAVA_OPTS"
 "$MAVEN_HOME/bin/mvn" -f "$GH_HOME/web/pom.xml" -Dgraphhopper.config=$CONFIG \
      -Dgraphhopper.osmreader.osm=$OSM_FILE -Djetty.reload=manual jetty:run


elif [ "x$ACTION" = "ximport" ]; then
 "$JAVA" $JAVA_OPTS -cp "$JAR" com.graphhopper.GraphHopper printVersion=true config=$CONFIG \
      graph.location="$GRAPH" \
      osmreader.osm="$OSM_FILE"


elif [ "x$ACTION" = "xtest" ]; then
 "$JAVA" $JAVA_OPTS -cp "$JAR" com.graphhopper.GraphHopper printVersion=true config=$CONFIG \
       graph.location="$GRAPH" osmreader.osm="$OSM_FILE" prepare.chShortcuts=false \
       graph.testIT=true


elif [ "x$ACTION" = "xmeasurement" ]; then
 ARGS="graph.location=$GRAPH osmreader.osm=$OSM_FILE prepare.chShortcuts=fastest osmreader.acceptWay=CAR"
 echo -e "\ncreate graph via $ARGS, $JAR"
 START=$(date +%s)
 "$JAVA" $JAVA_OPTS -cp "$JAR" com.graphhopper.GraphHopper $ARGS prepare.doPrepare=false
 END=$(date +%s)
 IMPORT_TIME=$(($END - $START))000

 function startMeasurement {
    COUNT=5000
    ARGS="$ARGS prepare.doPrepare=true measurement.count=$COUNT measurement.location=$M_FILE_NAME graph.importTime=$IMPORT_TIME"
    echo -e "\nperform measurement via $ARGS, $JAR"
    "$JAVA" $JAVA_OPTS -cp "$JAR" com.graphhopper.util.Measurement $ARGS
 }

 # use all <last_commits> versions starting from HEAD
 last_commits=$3

 if [ "x$last_commits" = "x" ]; then
   # use current version
   "$MAVEN_HOME/bin/mvn" -f "$GH_HOME/core/pom.xml" -DskipTests clean install assembly:single
   startMeasurement
   exit
 fi

 commits=$(git rev-list HEAD -n $last_commits)
 for commit in $commits; do
   git checkout $commit -q
   M_FILE_NAME=`git log -n 1 --pretty=oneline | grep -o "\ .*" |  tr " ,;" "_"`
   M_FILE_NAME="measurement$M_FILE_NAME.properties"
   echo -e "\nusing commit $commit and $M_FILE_NAME"

   "$MAVEN_HOME/bin/mvn" -f "$GH_HOME/core/pom.xml" -DskipTests clean install assembly:single
   startMeasurement
 done

fi
```

Comment: That first error message looks like something has DOS-style line endings (i.e. carriage return followed by linefeed, instead of just linefeed). Try printing the script with `cat -v graphhopper.sh` and look for "^M" at the end of lines.

Comment: yeah there are lots of ^Ms. What can I do now?

Comment: possible duplicate of [Find and remove DOS line endings on Ubuntu](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12508923/find-and-remove-dos-line-endings-on-ubuntu)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[Expanded from my comment...] The script file apparently has DOS-style line endings (i.e. carriage return followed by linefeed, instead of just linefeed). This confuses the shell greatly, since it sees the carriage return as part of the command. The giveaway is that first error message:

```
: not found.sh: 2: graphhopper.sh:
```

What's actually happened is it printed the error message "graphhopper.sh: 2: graphhopper.sh: ^M: not found" (where the ^M is actually a carriage return); when the terminal sees the ^M it goes back to the beginning of the line, and prints the end of the error message over top of the beginning.

One of the other effects this has is that the shell can't recognize keywords at the end of lines. When it sees a line like:

```
if [ ${OSM_FILE: -4} == ".pbf" ]; then^M
```

...it thinks `then^M` a regular command, not the end of the condition part of the `if` command, so it keeps looking for a `then`. But the `else` command seems to have some spaces at the end:

```
else    ^M
```

...which means the shell *does* recognize the `else` keyword and get very confused about what it's doing in the middle of the condition part of the `if`.

So what can you do about it? There's almost certainly a command for it; I'm used to `dos2unix`, but apparently ubuntu doesn't have that, instead the "tofrodos" package includes the command `fromdos` (see [here](http://ubuntuforums.org/showthread.php?t=1540180)). Or, you can do it with perl:

```
perl -pi -e 's/\r//g' graphhopper.sh
```

Your text editor may also be able to save in unix (rather than DOS) format. Speaking of which, you should either switch your text editor to unix mode, or find a different text editor for scripting.

Comment: Wow Thank you very much. That was the problem. Easily corrected using fromdos command.

Answer (score 1):

Remove the extra `fi`:

```
    if [ ! -f "$OSM_FILE" ]; then
      echo "ERROR couldn't download or extract OSM file $OSM_FILE ... exiting"
      exit
  #   fi
    else
      echo "## using existing osm file $OSM_FILE"
    fi
```

Comment: Your abridged example doesn't illustrate the problem.  Please include the entire script.

Comment: I modified my original post to include the whole script @Brian. Please look at it.

Answer (score 0):

The variable OSM_FILE is not set to anything. This causes it to expand to a empty string, which causes the shell to think there are syntax errors in the if conditions.

Print out the value of OSM_FILE before use, and if it's empty, debug backwards.

Comment: Yes. OSM_FILE value is set on run. I have to pass a value to that when I run the shell script as './graphhopper import new-York.osm'

Comment: Right. But have you confirmed that. By inserting an echo statement in your script right around the area where you are having the problem. Also, you need to put back in that "fi" someone asked you to comment out.

Comment: I do not know much about shell scripting. Please tell me exactly where I should have an echo statement and check?

Comment: The problem is the presence of DOS line endings in the file, as confirmed by the OP.