# "bad variable name" and "word expected" error in shell script

Tags: bash, shell

I'm creating a shell script to perform basic math operations using WSL. Im using ubuntu terminal for this purpose.

```
#!/bin/bash
echo "+ : Addition (a+b)"
echo "- : Subtraction (a-b)"
echo "* : Multiplication (a*b)"
echo "/ : Division (a/b)"
read -p "Choose operation: " op
read -p "Enter value of a: " a
read -p "Enter value of b: " b
case $op in
"+")
echo $a "+" $b "=" $((a+b))
;;
"-")
echo $a "-" $b "=" $((a-b))
;;
"*")
echo $a "*" $b "=" $((a*b))
;;
"/")
echo $a "/" $b "=" $((a/b))
;;
esac
```

this is the code.
Im executing this code using command

> sh add.sh

"add.sh" is the file name

and I'm getting
[image: this error message]

Comment: You have dos line endings in your script. Remove them.

Comment: How do I remove dos line endingds? @KamilCuk

Comment: A bit of google https://www.google.com/search?q=How+do+I+remove+dos+line+endingds%3F should help you. In command line with `dos2unix` program

Comment: ok "dos2unix" command worked for me. Thank you very much. @KamilCuk

Answer (score 0):

you have dos line endings. You can use fromdos to get rid of them

```
fromdos test.txt
```

> The above example would take a MS-DOS or Microsoft Windows file or
> other file with different line separators and format the file with new
> line separators to be read in Linux and Unix.

Ref: https://stackoverflow.com/a/12509995/1118978

Comment: Thanks. I used "dos2unix" command and it worked and "formdos" worked as well!

Comment: If this answer is useful for you, please consider to upvote and/or mark it as answer. thank you